# jFormer for production application?

Tags: jquery, jformer

Would anyone recommend using [jFormer](http://www.jformer.com/), specifically on a production application? There doesn't seem to be many reviews on it or live applications, however it seems like a pretty cool form framework.

Answer (score 0):

I am using it in an app now - and have found a couple of bugs in the code.
the huge issue I am facing as I write this is that I am having a significant amount of trouble re-populating the instances that i create when I am displaying a form in an 'edit' mode, so keep that in mind.

At this point I would recommend using it to play with but not for production unless a larger community grows behind it and/or you feel comfortable editing the framework on it's own.

I will post updates if/when I find a resolution to the 'instances in edit mode' - but in the meantime - I would just code things by hand, and sprinkle in your own jQuery if you need it.

Comment: did you use jFormer in production? I am looking for a good jquery form framework to use, regards